# Check if variable contains some string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this piece of code

```
 if ( x.str_NombreVariable == "User::v_sRutaArchivo")
                            x.str_ValorVariable += str_Archivo;
                        else if ( x.str_NombreVariable == "User::v_IdBitacoraCarga")
                        x.str_ValorVariable = _Bcarga.IdBitacoraCarga.ToString();
```

as you can see I do some comparissions: `x.str_NombreVariable == "User::v_sRutaArchivo"` `or x.str_NombreVariable == "User::v_IdBitacoraCarga"`

problem is that I have values into `x.str_NombreVariable` who doesn´t have `"User::"` and it don´t match with comparission. So I try to do something like:

```
"User::"+x.str_NombreVariable == "User::v_sRutaArchivo"
```

Problem is some `x.str_NombreVariable` come with "User::" as default so I get:

```
User::User::NombreVariable
```

and it is wrong I only need  User::NombreVariable

So in other words: How can I check if   `x.str_NombreVariable`  doesnt contains "User::" add it and if it have don´t do anything? it is possible? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the string starts with User:: and if it does not add it:

```
if (!x.str_NombreVariable.StartsWith("User::"))
    x.str_NombreVariable = "User::" + x.str_NombreVariable;
```

Put this code above yours and you should be good.

**Edit:** I just add missing ')'

Answer (score 0):

```
if ("User::v_sRutaArchivo".Contains(x.str_NombreVariable))
```

This condition will work in any scenario.

Comment: but if add string "User::" if it dont have? I want to add it if not

Comment: This piece of code works even without modifying the value of the variable. If you need to add the "User::" even after successfully comparing the values, then look at @Timo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to remove the "User::" part from your variable and the hardcoded string:

```
var nombreVar = x.str_NombreVariable.Replace("User::", "");
if ( nombreVar == "v_sRutaArchivo")
    x.str_ValorVariable += str_Archivo;
else if ( nombreVar == "v_IdBitacoraCarga")
    x.str_ValorVariable = _Bcarga.IdBitacoraCarga.ToString();
```